# Reverse Engineer a published Oneclick Vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

So i have this vb.net app using visual studio 2019 on a laptop.
I was published and currently being used. The Installation Mode is set to "Application is available online only" so the user doesn't have to install the app on their local machine. Instead it just need to send the Shortcut file from the ftp server to their desktop. A ClickOnce Application

My concern is; the laptop that i was using got corrupted and now I lost the source code and all the backup. The laptop was formatted and now i have no source code.

Is it possible to reverse engineer an already published vb.net app? i have looked for some tools but all of them only reverse engineer an installer (.exe) file. I can't find some tool or any guides on how to do it but with an run only apps.

Does anyone know?
Thank you

I have already tried searching in youtube and some forums but their solution only applied on installer files. mine is not an installer file but rather a ClickOnce Application

Comment: Are you looking for a decompiler? You would need access to the published app.

Comment: This seems like a bit of a tall tale. You're asking us to believe that you spent time creating an application, didn't create any sort of backup (or use any sort of source control), ended up with a corrupted disk drive, and then proceeded to format the drive?

Comment: Yes,  a decompiler. I tried JetBrains dotpeek. seems to work but it, decompiles to c#.